# Unable to import skeletonize in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-image

I am trying to import skeletonize() function from skimage.morphology but it is throwing some unusual error.

This very command was working fine until my recent Windows update.
The respective versions that I am running are:

numpy                     1.11.3

python                    3.5.6

scikit-image              0.14.0

This is the command

```
     from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
```

The error message that follows:

```
  File "<ipython-input-69-3b41733bed63>", line 5, in <module>
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize

 File "C:\Users\Nimesh Shahdadpuri\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\morphology\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .binary import (binary_erosion, binary_dilation, binary_opening,

 File "C:\Users\Nimesh Shahdadpuri\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\morphology\binary.py", line 6, in <module>
from .misc import default_selem

 File "C:\Users\Nimesh Shahdadpuri\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\morphology\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
from .._shared.utils import warn

 File "C:\Users\Nimesh Shahdadpuri\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\_shared\utils.py", line 10, in <module>
from ..util import img_as_float

 File "C:\Users\Nimesh Shahdadpuri\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from .apply_parallel import apply_parallel

 File "C:\Users\Nimesh Shahdadpuri\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\skimage\util\apply_parallel.py", line 8, in <module>
import dask.array as da

File "C:\Users\Nimesh Shahdadpuri\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\array\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .core import (Array, block, concatenate, stack, from_array, store,

File "C:\Users\Nimesh Shahdadpuri\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py", line 29, in <module>
from . import chunk

File "C:\Users\Nimesh Shahdadpuri\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\array\chunk.py", line 73, in <module>
nancumprod = npcompat.nancumprod

AttributeError: module 'dask.array.numpy_compat' has no attribute 'nancumprod'
```

Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: Looks related: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/4846

Comment: Already tried that

Comment: What have you tried? Your dask version is incompatible with your numpy version. You should either upgrade NumPy to 1.13 or higher, or downgrade dask to 1.2.0 or lower

Comment: @Juan Command for that?

Comment: Depends on how you installed them. Either `pip install -U numpy` or `conda update numpy`.

Comment: Tried updating the numpy module. Error still remains.